# How to add TextToSpeech.talk("hi') action to a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, text-to-speech

How to add TextToSpeech.talk("hi");  when button is selected/pressed.

```
TextToSpeech.talk("Hello Beautiful World!");
```

When user click on the button, the voice should be generated

TTS Github https://github.com/IonicaBizau/text-to-speech-js

[image]

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

Vue.config.productionTip = 

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <b-button-group vertical>
        <button v-on:click="say('hi')">Say hi</button>
        <button v-on:click="say('what')">Say what</button>
      </b-button-group>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? (Hint: you need to start by [creating a Vue method](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `click` handler is setup to call a local method named `say`, which takes a string argument (to be spoken). You just need to [define that method](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Method-Handler) in your component to call `TextToSpeech.talk()` with that string argument:

```
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    say(msg) {
      TextToSpeech.talk(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

However, you'll then notice that the `TextToSpeech` backend appears to be broken, as reported in [`IonicaBizau/text-to-speech-js` Issue #10](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/text-to-speech-js/issues/10).

[demo of broken lib](https://codesandbox.io/s/3427qmljn5)

Comment: thanks you for helping out the newbie with the snippet. very helpful!!

Comment: @DevEd No problem :)